# Disable Order Tax on specific Line Item

Tags: square-connect

I'm using the Square Connect Api V2 and was wondering if it is possible to create an Order, using the [Orders/createOrder](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createorder) endpoint, with an [Order-level tax](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-createorderrequesttax), and *disable* the tax for a specific line item?

As a work-around, I think I can move the Order-level tax to the line-item, but was hoping for the ability to disable tax or to find some other workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CreateOrder` and pass in a top-level `taxes` array, then this tax will be applied to all `line_items`. Simply do not include `taxes` as part of a `line_item` and it should work successfully, even if a tax is applied to the item in Dashboard.

Comment: OK. I was hoping to somehow disable the `top-level taxes array` from a specific `line_item`, but it looks like there is no way to do this.

Thank you for your answer! I'll move the taxes down to the individual `line_items`.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that, I misunderstood! You are correct, I don't believe this is currently possible.